# can't create user profile

Tags: django, function

The following code snippet (below) is causing an exception (see below), can someone explain why?

```
theUser = User.objects.get(id=user.id)
profile = User.objects.create(user=theUser)
```

These two lines cause an exception stating "user is an invalid keyword argument for this function" If I change the profile = line to be

```
profile = User.Objects.create(username, password, email)
```

Then I get an exception stating that "create" takes exactly 1 argument but received 4? What is the correct argument to send this function if not a user object?

Comment: Are you sure the User model has a user field which you can submit? Also can you copy your model so we actually know what the functions are supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

`user.objects.create` will make a User object, not a profile object, and as such requires arguments like username, email, etc. Perhaps you meant:

```
profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=theUser)
```

What is the name of the profile model?